# Abrir modal após submit de form

Tags: php, html

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um sistema de login, que caso o usuário digitar a senha ou email incorreto, apareça em janela modal que o os dados não correspondem ao digitado, porém quando a senha ou email são digitados incorretamente, a janela modal não está abrindo, fazendo com que o usuário pressione o botão para o mesmo abrir...Porém essa mensagem aparece, gostaria de saber como posso fazer com que a janela modal possa abrir..?

HTML:

```
            <div class="modal-body text-md-center">
      <form method="post" action="valida.php">
          <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group">

                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email:">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Senha:">
                  <br>
              </div>
          </div>

          <input type="submit" name="btnLogin" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-outline-warning"><br><br>
          <?php
              if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
                echo $_SESSION['msg'];

              }
            ?>
          <p class="text-center">
              Caso não possuir conta, <a href="#cadastrouser"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSelecionar" data-dismiss="modal">cadastre-se</a>
          </p>
      </form>
          </div>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
include("conexao.php");

$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
/* Verifica se existe usuario, o segredo ta aqui quando ele procupa uma 
linha q contenha o login e a senha digitada */
$sql_logar = "SELECT * FROM aluno WHERE email = '$email' && senha = '$senha'";
$exe_logar = mysqli_query($conection, $sql_logar) or die (mysqli_error());
$fet_logar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe_logar);
$num_logar = mysqli_num_rows($exe_logar);

//Verifica se n existe uma linha com o login e a senha digitado
if ($num_logar == 0){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Login ou senha incorreto!</div>";
    header("Location: index.php?login");

} 
else{
   //Cria a sessão e manda pra pagina principal.php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
   $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
   header("Location:aluno.php");
}
?>
```

Caso alguém tenha uma ideia do que possa ser feito, e puder ajudar serei grato!

Comment: Esse `?login` na URL do `index.php` é para identificar que a senha ou email foi digitado errado?

Comment: Não, esse ?login direciona quando o usuário digita errado.. Então quando o ?login aparecer quero que esteja com o modal aberto..

Comment: Essa modal é bootstrap? 3 ou 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o parâmetro `?login` é adicionado à URL quando o usuário é redirecionado ao errar as informações de login, você pode abrir a modal de forma manual, identificando se a URL contém `?login` com:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['login'])){
   // faz alguma coisa
}
?>
```

O `if` acima só será satisfeito de na URL tiver `?login` (ou `&login`, se `login` não for o primeiro parâmetro). Então no lugar de `// faz alguma coisa` você pode carregar um `script` para a abrir a modal:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['login'])){
?>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   $('#ID_DA_MODAL').modal('show');
});
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

No lugar de `ID_DA_MODAL`, você coloca o `id` da modal que quer abrir.

Comment: Funcionou Sam, muito obrigado!! estava faltando o método GET com essa script.. agora aprendi como faz.. Valeu mesmo!!